# Django - How to redirect to the same index page when clicked on Logo?

Tags: html, django

I have used static for all the js/css/images path. However, click on the logo redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index.html without any css/js/images. The same works well all other paths in the page(eg: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/about.html)

Sharing my *urls.py*:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

Please help

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nfew.png)

Comment: Can we get some html please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Websites generally need to serve additional files such as **images,
> JavaScript, or CSS**. In Django, we refer to these files as **“static
> files”**.

NOTE: **html files** are not included, so don't use `{% static %}` with `html` files.

To jump to other pages, you have to use `{% url %} tag` with the **name** of the view, for example `{% url 'index' %}` or simply use a relative path `<a href="/index.html">Home</a>`, that's good to go.

For css/js files are not loading, you may have the wrong settings, follow the [instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) here step by step, and remember to **`{% load static %}`** in the top of your template

Comment: Thanks @minglyu 
That worked. Also the documentation link was helpful. Thanks a lot